# "Fazer x anos": diferença entre PT-PT e PT-BR?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, verbos, diferenças-transatlânticas

Eu conheço a **expressão *"Fazer anos"*** em Portugal, tendo o significado de celebrar o aniversário (de nascimento). Pessoalmente, apenas costumo usar com este significado em específico.

> A) O meu filho faz 3 anos amanhã. [pt-PT]

Por outro lado, penso que no Brasil pode ser usado para mostrar a passagem do tempo, não necessariamente relacionada com aniversários.

> B) Faz 5 anos que cheguei a este país. [pt-BR]

Este nem me parece totalmente incorreto em pt-PT... Acho só que encontro mais frequentemente o uso de ***"há x anos"***, com a correspondente transformação da frase (se necessário), a menos que esteja a comparar explicitamente com um tempo que não o presente (e.g. *"Faz amanhã 3 anos que acabei"*, mas *"Acabei há 3 anos"* [= faz hoje]).

As minhas perguntas são então:

1. Estes significados são os **corretos**?
2. Algum dos significados pode ser **válido no outro país** (*A* no Brasil ou *B* em Portugal)?

Comment: No Brasil também usamos "faz X anos", "fez X anos" pra aniversários

Comment: bandrade, afinal descobri um diferença entre Portugal e Brasil no uso destas expressões. Relê a resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os dois significados estão corretos, e não são específicos de um país ou do outro. Por exemplo em [*fazer* no Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=fazer), um dicionário brasileiro, temos:

> **15** *impess* Ter decorrido; haver, completar-se (falando do tempo): *Faz nove dias que cheguei.* [...] ***Fazer anos:*** ver passar o seu aniversário natalício.

O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa tem em ***fazer:***

> **27.** Ter decorrido certo tempo. *Faz duas horas que estou aqui à espera. Fez ontem oito dias que ele esteve cá.* [...] **fazer anos**, comemorar o aniversário.

E para que ninguém fique a pensar que isto é só coisa de dicionários, vamos a umas citações. ***Fazer anos*** em autores brasileiros:

> Infelizmente a tua afilhada continua sem rumo. Já fez trinta anos, e parece ter vinte. ([Josué Montello](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josu%C3%A9_Montello), *A Última Convidada*, 1989.)
>
> Era um filho que ali estava, que fez dez anos, fez onze, fez doze, crescendo em altura e graça. ([Machado de Assis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machado_de_Assis), [*Memórias de Aires*, 1908.)](http://machado.mec.gov.br/images/stories/pdf/romance/marm10.pdf)

***Fazer tempo*** em publicações e autores portugueses:

> O filho, Rajiv, estava em campanha para recuperar o poder quando foi morto por uma bombista suicida, faz hoje quatro anos, em 20 de Maio de 1991. (Jornal *O Público*, 1995.)
>
> [...] que era dia de tristeza em casa, por fazer dezassete anos que morrera o mano Manuel. ([Eça de Queiroz](http://assaltaram%20e%20roubaram%20um%20marchante%20de%20Colos,), *Os Maias*, 1888.)
>
> Lembre-se que assaltaram e roubaram um marchante de Colos, aqui bem perto, faz agora um mês. ([Manuel da Fonseca](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_da_Fonseca_(escritor)), «A Testemunha», *O Fogo e as Cinza*, 1953.)

Onde parece haver uma diferença é que *faz tempo* para indicar a passagem de um período indeterminado de tempo é relativamente frequente no Brasil mas muito raro em Portugal. As expressões mais ou menos equivalentes *há tempos, há muito tempo, há algum tempo*, são usadas no dois países.

> Então Mãe Cândida disse, sem uma lágrima: ― já faz tempo que eu sabia. ([Dinah Silveira de Queiroz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Muralha_(livro)), [*A Muralha*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Muralha_(livro)), 1954.)
>
> Era exatamente uma escadinha assim que ele vinha procurando há tempos para tapar a buraqueira do teto de seu rancho. ([Paulo de Carvalho-Neto](https://www.ufo.com.br/dadosAutor.php?id=111&placeValuesBeforeTB_=savedValues&TB_iframe=true&height=450&width=750&modal=true), *Suomi*, 1986.)

A tabela abaixo mostra a frequência destas expressões no [CENTEMPúblico, corpus do jornal português *O Público*](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CETEMPUBLICO) e em textos portugueses e brasileitos do século XX neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/). Agora, *faz tempo* com este significado, lá por ser incomum, não deixa de ser válido mesmo em Portugal.

```
                  CENTEMPúblico      Corpus do Português      
                    Portugal         Portugal     Brasil
Faz tempo               2                0           22
Há tempos              79               48           56
Há muito tempo        452              188          176
Há algum tempo        299               52           58
```

Comment: Realmente, o segundo contexto não me parecia estranho em pt-PT. Acho só que talvez veja mais uso de **_"há x anos"_**, com a correspondente transformação da frase (se necessário), a menos que esteja a comparar explicitamente com um tempo que **não o presente** (e.g. _"Faz amanhã 3 anos que acabei"_, mas _"Acabei há 3 anos" [= faz hoje]_).

Comment: @bandrade *faz hoje* também se diz por cá. Incluí uma citação. Uma diferença que é capaz de existir é no Brasil usar-se bastante *faz tempo que* enquanto em Portugal se diz mais *há muito tempo que* ou *há tempos que* (não vou ao cinema, por exemplo).

Comment: Esse zero assusta um bocado. O CETEMPúblico tem duas ocorrências para "faz" "tempo": «... as obrigações do contrato de serviço público de televisão, assinado pela RTP já faz tempo.», «Mas mais polícias na rua não é a panaceia num país em que impera a escassez de meios materiais e humanos de análise, investigação e perseguição criminal -- de que, por exemplo, a Polícia Judiciária e a Procuradoria Geral, entre outras estruturas, se queixam, repetidamente, faz tempo.»

Comment: @Artefacto Ainda bem que encontraste isso. Adicionei os dados dos CETEMPúblico. Um zero nunca prova inexistência: as proporções das várias expressões do CENTEMPúblico estão de acordo com as do Corpus.

Comment: @Jacinto É verdade, como os valores são mais pequenos, aquele zero não é uma inexistência absoluta... No entanto, não deixa de mostrar a diferença proporcional de utilização. Obrigado também pelo esclarecimento em relação às restantes expressões.

Comment: @bandrade Claro. Aliás, na versão anterior da resposta eu tinha escrito que não se usava em Portugal (embora já tivesse escrito "lá por ser incomum). Depois é que o Artefacto me chamou a atenção para as duas ocorrências no CETEMPúblico, e eu acrescentei essa coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta sucinta:

"O meu filho caçula **faz três anos** amanhã." ou, sem o artigo, "Meu filho **faz três anos** amanhã." é de uso corrente em pt-BR.  Ao contrário de nossos amigos lusitanos, no entanto, não dizemos "tu vais aos anos da Maria?" com o significado de aniversário.

"**faz 5 anos** que cheguei a este país." também é de uso corrente em pt-BR, embora a camada menos alfabetizada da população, e até mesmo algumas pessoas bem letradas, erre frequentemente dizendo "fazem cinco anos..."

Poderíamos dizer também

> - Faz muito tempo que não como um risoto tão gostoso.
> - Não como um risoto tão gostoso há muito tempo.
> - Minha filha mais velha vai fazer quinze anos em breve.
> - Eu faço dezoito anos em dezembro.

Em um ambiente mais formal, talvez eu preferisse dizer "minha filha completa quinze anos em..."

Comment: Quem te disse que não usamos "faz três anos"?

Comment: @JorgeB. E quem te disse que eu disse que vocês não dizem?

Comment: Fui eu que li mal, peço desculpa.